# Couldn't Create a mercurial Repository

Tags: android, android-studio

I Used Git for Windows, Setup git.exe location and after that I received this error. 
How to fix this?
It is my first time using VCS.

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you do that caused these errors?

Comment: the path is not valid? 
It cannot find the hg.exe

Comment: Git <> Mercurial. If you used **Git for Windows**, why are you trying to create a **Mercurial** repository? They're not the same thing, any more than apples are the same as oranges just because they're both types of fruit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create a Mercurial repository or a Git repository? If the former, you need to [download Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). If it's the latter, you need to specify that you want to create a Git repo in Android Studio.

Comment: Okay thanks. Will try to download the mercurial.